# My WLAN-Connection is hidden even broadcast is on

Tags: wifi

I have an UMTS-Router. In the setup of the router the broadcast is on. But when wlan is disconnected for some reason it is not visible in network-manager-gnome. IPV6 is disabled on my system. `lspci -nnk | grep -i ath -A2` shows

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR928X Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002a] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Quanta Microsystems, Inc EM306 802.11bgn Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card [AR9283] [1a32:0306]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

`ath9k` is loaded with following options:

```
$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
options ath9k ps_enable=1
options ath9k nohwcrypt=1
```

After disconnecting, `iw wlan0 scan | grep -i ssid` did not show my connection. It showed others, but not mine.  I can connect over nmcli with `nmcli c up id xxxx`. The connection info is

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Digiworld 
[connection]
id=xxxx
uuid=cf380e60-ae56-405e-ba6c-82913b308d14
type=wifi
timestamp=1495540683

[wifi]
ssid=xxx
mode=infrastructure
mac-address=20:7C:8F:01:A1:61
seen-bssids=3C:46:D8:49:22:D3;
security=802-11-wireless-security

[wifi-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk-flags=1

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
method=ignore
ip6-privacy=0
```

Comment: Do `ip link` to find the name of your WLAN device. Assuming it's `wlan0`, do `iw wlan0 scan` as roout to find out if it's a device or network-manager problem.